# console.log on useState Hook array logs several times after GET request with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I have this React Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import "../../css/driversStandings.css";

function DriversStandingsComponent() {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    var row = 1;

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/standings").then(res => {
            const driversChampionshipData = res.data[0].DriversChampionship
            setData(driversChampionshipData);
            console.log(data)
        })
    });

    return (
          //Here I return a mdbootstrap table, mapping the data array
    )
}

export default DriversStandingsComponent;
```

[image: console.log several times]

I don't really understand why this happens, and if it affects the server performance.

Any idea for solving this? I don't even know if it's an error itself

Comment: It's possible you have `<React.StrictMode>` set, which will result in double logging in development only. But you should strip your `console.log`s before production anyway.

Comment: Indeed, I've `<React.StrictMode>` set. Thanks for the useful data I didn't know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

useEffect is called every time a component rerenders. You sholud add empty dependency array, that way useEffect calls only when component is mounted, like this:

```
   useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/standings").then(res => {
            const driversChampionshipData = res.data[0].DriversChampionship
            setData(driversChampionshipData);
            console.log(data)
        })
    }, []);
```

Comment: Docs to support this answer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects